# Add confirm password field in modelform in django only with one password field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I want to add the confirm password field in django modelform and validate both password and confirm password. After entering the details through template that data will be stored in database. But only three fields will be added to database such as firstname,lastname and email. so, i want to add the all fields data into database.

Here is my model:

```
class Register(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=False)
```

Here is my modelform :

```
class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    password_confirm = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
       model = Register
       fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email','password']

     def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(SignUpForm, self).clean()
        password = cleaned_data.get("password")
        confirm_password = cleaned_data.get("password_confirm")

        if password != confirm_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
            "password and confirm_password does not match"
            )
```

Here is my view.py file :

```
def auth_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           return HttpResponse('data has been saved...!!')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'auth-register.html', {'form': form})
```

Here is template code:

```
 <form method="post" action="">{%csrf_token%}

              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-6">
                  <label for="first_name">First Name : </label>
                  <input id="first_name" type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" autofocus="">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-6">
                  <label for="last_name">Last Name : </label>
                  <input id="last_name" type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group ">
                <label for="email">Email : </label>
                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email">
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                </div>
                </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-6">
                  <label for="password1" class="d-block">Password</label>
                  <input id="password1" type="password" class="form-control pwstrength" data-indicator="pwindicator" name="password1">
                  <div id="pwindicator" class="pwindicator">
                    <div class="bar"></div>
                    <div class="label"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-6">
                  <label for="password_confirm" class="d-block">Password Confirmation</label>
                  <input id="password_confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password2">
                </div>
              </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="agree" class="custom-control-input" id="agree">
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="agree">I agree with the terms and conditions</label>
                </div>
                </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
                  Register
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: You can use Django's [built-in authentication views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#all-authentication-views), You don't have to reinvent the wheel

Comment: So what is the exact problem? You're not telling us what isn't working.

Comment: I hope this is just a test project, because saving passwords in your database this way is **not the way you should do it**!

Comment: what exact my problem is, i have password field in model. for that  i want to add confirm password field in modelform and validate both password and confirm password . After that when i just click the submit button that data should be stored in database.

Comment: This is about register the user details.